# Adding signature in addThis android app

Tags: android, addthis

I am developing a news reader type android app. From this app user can share his favorite news link in Facebook or Twitter. Link sharing facility is provided by [addThis](http://www.addthis.com/help/android-quickstart#.T0XiThAqBMU) android library. Now I want to add a signature when posting link (like: "shared via MyNewsReaderApp"). But there is no option to add a signature string. I don't want to append the signature string with news description. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the signature jar file in your application and then get the signature from the user. That signature can be stored in your sd card or where you want i.e. we have to give the path for that.

```
String  fileName;
```

static  Bitmap bitmap;
private static final int CAPTURE_REQUEST_CODE = 0;

```
/**
 * 
 */
Intent intent;
private void startCaptureActivity() {


     intent = new Intent("biz.binarysolutions.signature.CAPTURE");



    String keyFileName    = "biz.binarysolutions.signature.FileName";
    String keyTitle       = "biz.binarysolutions.signature.Title";
    String keyStrokeWidth = "biz.binarysolutions.signature.StrokeWidth";
    String keyCrop        = "biz.binarysolutions.signature.Crop";
    String keyWidth       = "biz.binarysolutions.signature.Width";
    String keyHeight      = "biz.binarysolutions.signature.Height";

  fileName    = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/imdad.png";    // set the file name (global write permissions)
    //String  title       = "Imdad app";    // optional, default is set in AndroidManifest.xml
    int     strokeWidth = 10;    // optional, default is 12
    boolean crop        = false; // optional, default is true

    // allowed units: px, dp, dip, sp, pt, mm, in
    String width  = "600dip"; // optional, default is max
    String height = "300dip"; // same as above

    intent.putExtra(keyFileName, fileName);
    //intent.putExtra(keyTitle, title);
    intent.putExtra(keyStrokeWidth, strokeWidth);
    intent.putExtra(keyCrop, crop);
    intent.putExtra(keyWidth, width);
    intent.putExtra(keyHeight, height);
    //Log.v("FILE SAVE ",fileName);
    Button done=new Button(this);
    done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    });
//  startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_REQUEST_CODE);


}
```

This is the code to add the signature app andjar file you can purchase from the [biz.binarysolutions](http://biz.binarysolutions.com)

Comment: Thanks Naresh for your effort, but this is not the solution I wanted. I don't want to give any option to the user to add his signature. I just want to add a simple string at the end of the posted link, so that the link viewer can see from which app the link is shared. If you send an email from BlackBerry, it will attach a line "sent from my BlackBerry"; I want to implement feature similar to this. Any other suggestion please?